# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to render image dynamically. But I am getting this error. What is the solution for getting image source dynamically and rendering that ?

**MainComponent.js**

```
const iconsNames =[
{image:"require('../pngIcons/the-statue-of-liberty.png')"},
]

iconsNames.map(function(item, index){
   return (
      <CardDetails  key={index} data={ item } />
          )
 .bind(this))
```

**CardDetails.js**

```
return(
<Image  style={{width: 130, height: 140}} source= {this.props.data.image} />
)
```

I tried other methods too but could not succed. I get this error while using this method:

> Unknown named module

**MainComponent.js**

```
 const iconsNames =[
   {image:'../pngIcons/the-statue-of-liberty.png'}
  ]
```

**CardDetails.js**

```
  var Img = require(''+this.props.data.image);
  return (
     <Image  style={{width: 130, height: 140}} source= {Img} />
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need quotes around `require('...')`, just do:

```
const iconsNames = [
    {image: require('../pngIcons/the-statue-of-liberty.png')},
]
```